# Глобальные переменные между классами

Tags: c#, классы, namespace

Есть 3 класса

```
class A
{
    List<double> tables = new List<double>();
    B b = new B();
}

class B
{
    C c = new C();
}

class C
{

}
```

Необходимо воспользоваться в классе C полями класса A. Как это возможно сделать? Вне классов создавать переменные нельзя, дальше уже `namespace`

Comment: передать нужные поля в конструктор, например

Comment: У вас невалидный код.

Comment: сделайте эти поля публичными свойствами (или публичными полями) и обращайтесь к ним, создав экземпляр класса. Если хотите "по-взрослому", то реализуйте через Dependency Injection

Comment: @DreamChild можно подробнее про Dependency Injection ?

Comment: @DreamChild Вот как раз таки объект создавать экземпляр объекта не получится, т.к. необходимы значения уже созданного объекта. Грубо говоря, я уже создал объект A со всеми своими полями. И у класса С необходимо узнать свойства уже созданного объекта. Либо же вынести в глобальные переменные необходимые поля созданного объекта А.

Comment: @Сергей это довольно обширная тема, и в рамках комментария её не опишешь. Если вкратце, то классы не должны привязываться к конкретным реализациям своих зависимостей и вообще не должны ничего знать о них, кроме их интерфейса

Comment: @Fresto передавайте уже созданный объект в конструктор либо через сеттер

Comment: @DreamChild просто тогда придется передавать нужное поле вначале в конструктор класса А, затем в конструктор класса В, и затем в конструкторе класса В передавать в конструктор класса С. И если таких 3 параметра, то это 3 раза писать одно и тоже. Вместо того, чтобы как-нибудь сделать глобальные переменные для 3 классов и использовать их без передачи по конструкторам.

Comment: Рекомендую к просмотру [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSbix3v6AUY)

Comment: @Fresto именно так, передавать в конструктор. Иначе (если у вас проект сложнее helloworld) замучаетесь с глобальными переменными

Comment: @DreamChild я вас понял, если что, буду дальше уж так, но попробую всё же со статик полями, как в ответе написали) Спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор, если тебе действительно нужны "глобальные переменные", то в .NET это static-поля и свойства.

```
class A
{
    static List<double> tables = new List<double>();
    static B b = new B();
}

class B
{
    C c = new C();
}

class C
{
  void Do()
  {
    var b = A.b;
    var table = A.tables;
    ...
  }
}
```

Но если тебе нужно просто разделить общий ресурс между несколькими компонентами, то ты либо передаёшь один в конструктор или метод другого, делая поля/свойства публичными, либо выносишь их в отдельный класс-контекст, который спускаешь в конструктор/метод каждого класса, который их использует. Основы ООП.

Comment: Что-то я про статик поля забыл, статик методы использую, а про поля забыл) Спасибо большое!)